# What type of primer to use on stucco wall?

Tags: paint, waterproofing, stucco

So our stucco comes up about 3 feet off the ground and then the siding takes over. We had our deck removed and installed a nice new patio. I would like to do something with the stucco wall because it's dirty from years of neglect. We don't have any issues with water getting into the basement but I wouldn't mind making it waterproof (if possible).

Can I use Drylok? And what about painting it a beige color, white would get too dirty.[image]